# Vue router and laravel SPA

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

this is my code for my module that will be compiled by gulp laravel elixir

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

import axios from 'axios';

import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';


Vue.use(VueAxios,axios,VueRouter);


axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = Laravel.csrfToken;

const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
});

const app = new Vue({
  router,
 // render: h => h(app)
}).$mount('#app')
```

and this my app.blade.php the main template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
   <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>
    <!-- use router-link component for navigation. -->
    <!-- specify the link by passing the `to` prop. -->
    <!-- <router-link> will be rendered as an `<a>` tag by default -->
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
  </p>
  <!-- route outlet -->
  <!-- component matched by the route will render here -->
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script> 


</body>
</html>
```

Im really having a hard time because when i compile it i receive an error that router-link is not registered but when i put my script tags on the upper part

## app is not found

how can i make this thing work?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC: an html renders at server-side, with a script injected to it, the script contains your compiled vue component, and will mount it to a node in the dom. Which means, the php file containing `router-link` will only be passed through php parser, who have no idea what `router-link` is. Only front end compilers know how to handle `router-link`, so you need to put it in your vue component's template (to make it go through front end compiler who understands it). Also, when you're mounting to `#app`, contents inside it will be overwritten by vue, so avoid putting useful things inside, but reorganize your html or put them in your vue component instead.